# How to override the location of .ivy2 directory when using sbt?

Tags: ivy, sbt

I'm using the xsbt 0.6.10 launcher. I would like the ivy files and jar files to be downloaded under a different directory. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sbt 0.6.12, this can be done by overriding `ivyCacheDirectory`:

```
override def ivyCacheDirectory = Some(path("../ivycache"))
```

See [0.6.11 announcement](http://groups.google.com/group/simple-build-tool/browse_thread/thread/81af7649abe20fb9/1a2d134319512e5c) and [IvyInterface](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/IvyInterface) for references.